# Performance tuning on String search using PATINDEX.

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following query to search the string using the PATINDEX.

Query:

```
SELECT [Employee First Name],[Employee Last Name],[Employee Middle Name],[Gender]............
FROM OPENQUERY([LinkDB],'SELECT [Employee First Name],[Employee Last Name],[Employee Middle Name],[Gender]............ FROM [LinkDB].dbo.[Employee]') 
WHERE ISNULL(PATINDEX('%Jack%',[Employee First Name]),'0') + ISNULL(PATINDEX('%Jack%',[Employee Last Name]),'0')  >= '1'
```

Data Details:

> DATABASE    : LinkDB
>   Columns         : 60
>   Data        : 10 Millions
>   INDEX       : [Employee Number],[Employee First Name],[Employee Last Name]

Statistics:

> Query       : Above query
>   Rows        : 90,505
>   Time taken  : 00:02:45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with adding the `WHERE` clause to the query. Note, I have change the code a little bit to make it work with my environment:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY([RMVNSQL01\INST1],'SELECT  [login], [FirstName], [LastName] FROM [smModel_20180807_UpdateTests_CORE].dbo.[SecurityUsers]') 
WHERE ISNULL(PATINDEX('%emil%',[FirstName]),'0') + ISNULL(PATINDEX('%emil%',[LastName]),'0')  >= '1'

SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY([RMVNSQL01\INST1],'SELECT  [login], [FirstName], [LastName] FROM [smModel_20180807_UpdateTests_CORE].dbo.[SecurityUsers] WHERE ISNULL(PATINDEX(''%emil%'',[FirstName]),''0'') + ISNULL(PATINDEX(''%emil%'',[LastName]),''0'')  >= ''1''')
```

You can see, in your case we have remote scan, then filter. In the second, the filter pass is missing:

[image]

Also, if you can add an indexes, you can add index on `first` and `last` name and try first selecting only the rows that need to be returned:

```
CREATE TABLE #EmployeesFiltered 
(
    [EmployeeID] INT 
);

INSERT INTO #EmployeesFiltered ([EmployeeID])
SELECT [EmployeeID]
FROM [LinkDB].dbo.[Employee]
WHERE ISNULL(PATINDEX('%Jack%',[Employee First Name]),'0') + ISNULL(PATINDEX('%Jack%',[Employee Last Name]),'0')  >= '1';

SELECT *
FROM [LinkDB].dbo.[Employee] A
INNER JOIN  #EmployeesFiltered B
    ON A.[EmployeeID] = B.[[EmployeeID];
```

Even if you are not allowed to rely the indexes ordering, you will work with smaller amount of data, when the indexes is read (you need only to read all users IDs, first and last names. Then having the IDs, just filter the clustered index.